# Why does a formula not work for the same data when changing the reference cells

Tags: excel, validation, formula

I have this problem For the same formula in sheet `A` and Sheet `B`. I need the Length value to be greater than 0 and equal to value of cell in sheet `A` for example

In sheet `A`, I put Code “eac” and  length  = 125.
In sheet `B`, I input this:

```
Code    Length  
eac     100     ok
eac     25      ok
eac     25      ok
```

This code below only works when code “eac” in sheet ‘A’  is in A2 but when I put it in another cell the formula does not works

```
=IF('A'!$C4:$C152=C4;'A'!$M4:$M152>=O4;O4="")
```

Can you please explain to me what doesn't work?

Comment: I have tried to clarify the language, but I'm still not sure I understand the problem. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54405953/edit) to give us screen caps of you data, and what the expected result is?

Comment: Are you entering this as an array formula? Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your formula suggests to me that you are trying to use an array function.
In which case pressing Control-Shift-Enter might help.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/02/25/array-formulas-functions-excel/